# highchart total in tooltip

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

i am using this code to display a shared tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true,
    headerFormat: 'KW {point.key}<table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style=\"color: {series.color}\">{series.name}: <b></td><td>{point.y} USD</b></td></tr>',
    useHTML: true,
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    valueDecimals: 2
},
```

Now i like to add all point.y values as a total value of the point. But how can i loop the point.y of each series to calculate the total value?

Answer (score 10):

Excatly, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/65bpvudh/7/

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>',
            sum = 0;

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+
                point.y +'m';
            sum += point.y;
        });

        s += '<br/>Sum: '+sum

        return s;
    },
    shared: true
},
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but now "this.x" will display 1335398400000 for example and dont display the date in the format %Y-%m-%d

Comment: It is timestamp so you can use Highcharts dateFormat() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat() to translate timestamp to date.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`footerFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.footerFormat) property (since version 2.2) with `{point.total}` to easily show the total without having to re-define the complete `formatter` function:

```js
tooltip: {
    footerFormat: 'Sum: <b>{point.total}</b>',
    shared: true,
},
```

Answer (score 4):

More easy, use total property of point:

```js
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+ point.y;
        });
        s += '<br/>Total: '+ this.points[0].total
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
},
```

Check this [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.total)